# Use Parse Query in then() when using Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I can’t seem to get this simple Parse query to work in my cloud code `then()` it works outside of this but when i place the code inside of this then function nothing happens. The variables are just placeholders for now in terms of testing but i have the default TestObject class you get when you start Parse from the beginning but for some reason it just keeps on returning nothing.

Here is the full function that i am currently using.

```
// Function which will get the data from all the links passed into the function
Parse.Cloud.define("myNews", function (request, response) {

    var promises = _.map(import_io_keys, function (news_api_key) {

        return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({

            method: 'GET',
            url:     "https://api.import.io/store/connector/" + news_api_key + "/_query?input=webpage/url:https%3A%2F%2Fwww.designernews.co%2Fnew&&_apikey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
            }

        }).then(function (httpResponse) {

            result = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text);

            var success = false;
            var news_icon = "";
            var news_source_name = "";

            var query = new Parse.Query("TestObject");
            query.find({

                success: function(results) {

                    success = true;

                    news_icon = results[0].get("foo");
                    news_source_name = results[0].get("foo");
                    response.success("done" + news_icon);

                },
                error: function() {

                   success = false;
                    response.error("Query lookup failed");
                }
            });

            for (var story in result.results) {

                if(story.length > 0){

                    if (story["article_link/_text"] !== "" && story["article_link"] !== "" && story["article_time"] !== "") {

                        if(success){

                            // Do the stuff later
                        }

                    }
                }

            }

        });
    });

    Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function () {

        console.log("Got all the stories");
        response.success(newsJsonData);

    }, function () {
        response.error("No stories");
        console.log("API KEY IS: " + request.params.keys);
    });

});
```

Comment: What response message your client receives when you call your cloud function ? null, empty string or something else ? How do you fill your "newsJsonData" variable ?

Comment: @toofoo It returns nothing from the success or error also the newsJsonData isn't important as of now with the current code.